# Can not find .create method using i2cdevice (following GrovePi samples .net core iot)

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I have a GrovePi+ starter kit and followed some instructions in the manual. Sadly the GrovePi library only works for UWP app's and not for .net core app's.

Basically what I want to achieve is controlling my led light within a .net core web API. Since I can not use the given library in that application I'm following their samples for .net core apps: https://github.com/dotnet/iot/blob/master/src/devices/GrovePi/samples/Program.cs

I'm following their sample but I have the following problem :

There is not a. Create a method for I2cDevice

but in their sample, they are using a .create method

`grovePi = new GrovePi(I2cDevice.Create(i2CConnectionSettings));`

[image]

I just want to control the LEDs in a .net core web application but it's even impossible to use their samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GPIO Support for Raspberry Pi is a new feature in .net core 3.0, please see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#gpio-support-for-raspberry-pi). The GPIO packages include APIs for GPIO, SPI, I2C, and PWM devices. You need to build the app with .net core 3.0. And you need to open the sample with Visual Studio 2019, which include the target for .net core 3.0. And you can update the  System.Device.Gpio package to latest version.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will check at home if it's possible to use the grovepi libary in there

Comment: Ok, please feel free let me know you fixed the issue.

Comment: I have opened the sample in VS 2019 and changed the target to .Net Core 3.0. Getting the following error:  Unable to find project information for 'C:path/GrovePiDevice.csproj'

Comment: @Ogie, you need to add the project GrovePiDevice to current solution manually, otherwise the project can not find the GrovePiDevice which is a reference.

Comment: Thank you, so in order to controll my led lights from my .net core webapi I need to add these 2 projects to my .net core webapi right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Or you can build the project as a dll library, but please note that you need to build it for ARM platform.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try to add the project to my .net core webapi and try it on my pi.